# The delay in the activation of review buttons is not enforced by the server

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, review-abuse

You are forced to wait a few seconds before you can do any review action (such as approving or rejecting a suggested edit), I suppose because they don't want you to mindlessly review things.

This constraint is not enforced by the server, and is very easy to get around. For example, on the [suggested edits page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/), you can just run this script in the browser's console to keep the Approve/Reject buttons enabled:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("input[value=Approve], input[value=Reject]").each(function() {
        this.disabled = false;
    });
}, 50);​
```

If you really want to enforce the wait period, shouldn't it be enforced on the server side? Otherwise, is there really any point to introducing a slightly annoying constraint that can easily be circumvented?

Honest editors who occasionally can review a post in such a short time span will only be annoyed by it, and as it currently stands, it doesn't do anything to prevent a capricious reviewer from automatically submitting erroneous reviews in quick succession.

Comment: Yes, you can circumvent it. But I would think that the majority simply doesn't, making this a theoretical possibility only. I don't think we have a real problem on our hands. And just take your time reviewing.

Comment: @Bart It would become a problem if somebody were to compromise the integrity of the review queues by automatically approving/rejecting things.

Comment: The pattern of abuse is pretty obvious though, I doubt that someone doing this would be allowed to continue to review.

Comment: I don't think the current delay system is designed to stop actively malicious reviewers. Seems more like it's for preventing people from accidentally submitting two reviews by double-clicking on a review button.

Answer (score 7):

The client-side delay is not exactly in sync with the server-side validation, but rapid-fire reviews will eventually be automatically invalidated, in similar fashion to upvote and downvote invalidation.